# How do I use row_number in Hive query to get the latest user login?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have this query which runs fine

The log table looks like this

`reportid, timestamp, userid`

```
SELECT
  reportid,
  b.email
FROM
  logs
  JOIN mongo.user b on a.userid = b.id
WHERE
  a.dt >= date_sub(current_date, 14)
GROUP BY
  reportid,
  b.email
```

The result will be something like this

```
reportid, email
1, xxx@xxx.com
1, xxx1@xxx.com
```

However, I want the result to just be

```
reportid, email
1, xxx1@xxx.com
```

This is just based on the timestamp. I learned about `row_number` but when I added this

`row_number() over (partition by userid order by timestamp desc)`

I get this error

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies. Underlying error: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Line 7:34 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'userid'

I just want the userid who accessed the report the latest based on the timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for the latest userid accessing the report,then sort the records by timestamp descending and get the first row using `limit`

```
select userid, b.email
from  logs a
join mongo.user b on a.userid = b.id
where  a.dt >= date_sub(current_date, 14)
sort by timestamp desc 
limit 1
```

If you are looking to get the list of users and their latest timestamps of accessing the reports then you need to give `row_number()` column a name and use it to get the 1 row for each userid group.

```
select userid,email
from
(
    select userid, b.email, row_number() over (partition by userid order by timestamp desc) as r_no
    from  logs a
    join mongo.user b on a.userid = b.id
    where  a.dt >= date_sub(current_date, 14)
) t
where t.r_no=1
```